# Cassandra materialized view on collection truncate

Tags: cassandra, truncate, materialized-views

If I truncate the entire source table in Cassandra. How will the MV(materialized views)'s have that reflection.

Does this process may create parity between source partition and MV's if the data is continuously inserted into the source partition?

can you please explain the flow of collection truncate with materialize view involved?

FYI my usecase is that: I will have regular ingrace of CURD operation on source partitions and there in between there will be a collection truncate request. so does Cassandra will ensure that there won't be any Parity between MV and source partition?